# Extracting drop-down values with document.querySelector() - multiple ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have an app that contains a series of `<select>` dropdowns and based on a user's selection tells the browser to `alert()` a unique sentence. The dropdowns also `show()` or `hide()` based on previous selections, they are tied to each other.

I am attempting to create a variable that uses `document.querySelector` or something similar to form a portion of the `alert()` output. The two id's `"s4"` and `"s5"` contain values that are very similar but these dropdowns will never be displayed at the same time. To do this, I want to create a single statement that will apply to both id's.

I have successfully created every portion of the output aside from the last statement which uses `document.querySelector`. This is the primary function, I will include the entire code file below:

```
function alertCar(){

  //make
  var input1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
  //models
  var input2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
  var input3 = document.getElementById("s3").value;
  //drivetrain
  var drivetrainids = document.querySelector("#s4", "#s5").value;
  var input4;
  if (drivetrainids == "FWD"){
      input4 = "This car is front-wheel drive";
  }
  else if (drivetrainids == "AWD"){
      input4 = "This car is all-wheel drive";
  }
  else if (drivetrainids == "RWD"){
      input4 = "This car is rear-wheel drive";
  }
```

Here is the entire code file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">

<style type="text/css">
  .chosen-select {width:200px}
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      disable_search_threshold: 4
    });

//BMW Start
  $("#s1").chosen().change(function(){
         if ($(this).val() === 'BMW'){
           $("#s2").parent().show();
         }
         else {
           $("#s2").parent().hide();
           $("#s5").parent().hide();
         }
     });

   $("#s2").chosen().change(function(){
          if ($(this).val() === 'X1','X2'){
            $("#s5").parent().show();
          }
          else {
            $("#s5").parent().hide();
          }
      });

//BMW End

//Audi Start
  $("#s1").chosen().change(function(){
         if ($(this).val() === 'AUDI'){
           $("#s3").parent().show();
         }
         else {
           $("#s3").parent().hide();
           $("#s4").parent().hide();
         }
     });

   $("#s3").chosen().change(function(){
          if ($(this).val() === 'Q1','Q3'){
            $("#s4").parent().show();
          }
          else {
            $("#s4").parent().hide();
          }
      });

 //Audi End


  function hide() {
    $("#s2").parent().hide();
    $("#s3").parent().hide();
    $("#s4").parent().hide();
    $("#s5").parent().hide();

  }
  // call hide AFTER .chosen() has been invoked on the visible elements
  hide();

 });

//alert

function alertCar(){

  //make
  var input1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
  //models
  var input2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
  var input3 = document.getElementById("s3").value;
  //drivetrain
  var drivetrainids = document.querySelector("#s4", "#s5").value;
  var input4;
  if (drivetrainids == "FWD"){
      input4 = "This car is front-wheel drive";
  }
  else if (drivetrainids == "AWD"){
      input4 = "This car is all-wheel drive";
  }
  else if (drivetrainids == "RWD"){
      input4 = "This car is rear-wheel drive";
  }


//Alert outputs
  if (input1 == "BMW"){
    alert("This is a BMW "+input2+". "+input4+"!");
  }
  else if (input1 == "AUDI"){
    alert("This is an Audi "+input3+". "+input4+"!");
  }
}

 </script>


</head>

<body onload="hide()">

 <table>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select Brand" class="chosen-select" id="s1">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
          <option value="AUDI">AUDI</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select BMW Model" class="chosen-select" id="s2">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="X1">X1</option>
          <option value="X2">X2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select Audi Model" class="chosen-select" id="s3">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="Q1">Q1</option>
          <option value="Q3">Q3</option>
        </select>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select Audi Drivetrain" class="chosen-select" id="s4">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="FWD">Front-wheel drive</option>
          <option value="AWD">Quattro all-wheel drive</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select BMW Drivetrain" class="chosen-select" id="s5">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="FWD">Front-wheel drive</option>
          <option value="AWD">X-Drive all-wheel drive</option>
          <option value="RWD">Rear-wheel drive</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button id="b1" onclick="alertCar()">Submit</button>


 </body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">

<style type="text/css">
  .chosen-select {width:200px}
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      disable_search_threshold: 4
    });

//BMW Start
  $("#s1").chosen().change(function(){
         if ($(this).val() === 'BMW'){
           $("#s2").parent().show();
         }
         else {
           $("#s2").parent().hide();
           $("#s5").parent().hide();
         }
     });

   $("#s2").chosen().change(function(){
          if ($(this).val() === 'X1','X2'){
            $("#s5").parent().show();
          }
          else {
            $("#s5").parent().hide();
          }
      });

//BMW End

//Audi Start
  $("#s1").chosen().change(function(){
         if ($(this).val() === 'AUDI'){
           $("#s3").parent().show();
         }
         else {
           $("#s3").parent().hide();
           $("#s4").parent().hide();
         }
     });

   $("#s3").chosen().change(function(){
          if ($(this).val() === 'Q1','Q3'){
            $("#s4").parent().show();
          }
          else {
            $("#s4").parent().hide();
          }
      });

 //Audi End


  function hide() {
    $("#s2").parent().hide();
    $("#s3").parent().hide();
    $("#s4").parent().hide();
    $("#s5").parent().hide();

  }
  // call hide AFTER .chosen() has been invoked on the visible elements
  hide();

 });

//alert

function alertCar(){

  //make
  var input1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
  //models
  var input2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
  var input3 = document.getElementById("s3").value;
  //drivetrain
  var drivetrainids = document.querySelector("#s4", "#s5").value;
  var input4;
  if (drivetrainids == "FWD"){
      input4 = "This car is front-wheel drive";
  }
  else if (drivetrainids == "AWD"){
      input4 = "This car is all-wheel drive";
  }
  else if (drivetrainids == "RWD"){
      input4 = "This car is rear-wheel drive";
  }


//Alert outputs
  if (input1 == "BMW"){
    alert("This is a BMW "+input2+". "+input4+"!");
  }
  else if (input1 == "AUDI"){
    alert("This is an Audi "+input3+". "+input4+"!");
  }
}

 </script>


</head>

<body onload="hide()">

 <table>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select Brand" class="chosen-select" id="s1">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
          <option value="AUDI">AUDI</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select BMW Model" class="chosen-select" id="s2">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="X1">X1</option>
          <option value="X2">X2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select Audi Model" class="chosen-select" id="s3">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="Q1">Q1</option>
          <option value="Q3">Q3</option>
        </select>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select Audi Drivetrain" class="chosen-select" id="s4">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="FWD">Front-wheel drive</option>
          <option value="AWD">Quattro all-wheel drive</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select data-placeholder="Select BMW Drivetrain" class="chosen-select" id="s5">
          <option disabled selected></option>
          <option value="FWD">Front-wheel drive</option>
          <option value="AWD">X-Drive all-wheel drive</option>
          <option value="RWD">Rear-wheel drive</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button id="b1" onclick="alertCar()">Submit</button>


 </body>
</html>
```

I am not too familiar with `document.querySelector`. I'd also be open to other recommended solutions. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Two points.  `'string', 'string'` is not a valid selector, as a selector is intended to be a **single** string.  `'#id1, #id2'`.  Second point.  `querySelector` returns only one element, not multiple.  Use `querySelectorAll` if you expect multiple results.

Comment: Third point, it's a code smell why you are reverting to using the querySelector when you have jQuery logic included.

Comment: @taplar I used a valid selector. See code  `var drivetrainids = document.querySelector("#s4", "#s5").value;`. I am attempting to return one result. I am evaluating both ID's because they are similar but only one is displayed at a time based on previous selections.

Comment: This is not a valid selector.  You are giving it two strings...  If only one is expected, then `var drivetrainids` being plural is misleading

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to alter how you're suppressing the two select elements, by applying a class set to `display: none;` rather than using `show()` and `hide()`.  Then you could use the `:not()` pseudo-selector to check for the presence of the class.

Since `querySelector` will return `null`, if no element is found, you can use that as the logic check in a ternary expression and grab the value from whichever select was showing.

Here's a simple example to illustrate the idea:

```js
// Select all ".example1" spans
var example1Spans = document.querySelectorAll(".example1");
console.log("Example 1 spans: ", example1Spans);

// Select only the default ".example1" span
var defaultSpan = document.querySelectorAll(".example1:not(.highlighted)");
console.log("Default example 1 span: ", defaultSpan);

// Log the value of the visible ".example2" span
var visibleSpan = (document.querySelector("#example2Span1:not(.hidden)")) ?
                   document.querySelector("#example2Span1") :
                   document.querySelector("#example2Span2");

console.log("Example 2 visible content: ", visibleSpan.textContent);
```

```css
.highlighted {background-color: yellow;}
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<h1>Highlighted span example:</h1>
<div>
  Default Span ==&gt; <span id="example1Span1" class="example1">Default content</span> &lt;==<br />
  Highlighted Span ==&gt; <span id="example1Span2" class="example1 highlighted">Highlighted content</span> &lt;==
</div>

<h1>Hidden span example:</h1>
<div>
  Hidden Span ==&gt; <span id="example2Span1" class="example2">Span 1 content (visible)</span> &lt;==<br />
  Visible Span ==&gt; <span id="example2Span2" class="example2 hidden">Span 2 content (hidden)</span> &lt;==
</div>
```

That last bit of code is closest to what you would have to do in you're scenario.  if you were to set up a similar "hidden" class, like so:

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

. . . and use that to suppress your "s4" and "s5" `<select>` elements, you would be able to grab just the visible one using:

```
var visibleDriveTrainSelect = (document.querySelector("#s4:not(.hidden)")) ?
                               document.querySelector("#s4") :
                               document.querySelector("#s5");
var drivetrainids = visibleDriveTrainSelect.value;
```

You could even condense it further, if you wanted to:

```
var drivetrainids = (document.querySelector("#s4:not(.hidden)")) ?
                     document.querySelector("#s4").value :
                     document.querySelector("#s5").value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have implemented it, switching over to the `.hidden {display: none}` logic as you have suggested. With your update, I am only receiving a drivetrain output for one of the vehicle brands, not both.

Comment: @mugelloblue - Okay, maybe I misunderstood, your issue . . . I thought you were saying that you were only wanting to retrieve the value from the `<select>` that was currently visible.  Can you explain again what the behavior is that you are looking for?  I'll try to alter the logic to fit that.